# Allow iframe to access parent window object and set properties to it

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm trying to have an `iframe` access its parent `window` object and set properties to it. At the moment this is **not served** by a web server or anything. I just have 2 `.html` files one for the parent page and one for the `iframe` content and inside it, I'm trying to use a `<script>` tag to set a simple variable on the parent's `window` object.

I'm using `window.parent.test = "";` but I'm getting this:

> Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

I also tried `window.top.test = "";` but to no avail. I have added the following attributes on the `iframe` tag:

`sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-top-navigation allow-scripts allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-popups"`

but it still doesn't work...

Comment: Are you on https or the file protocol?

Comment: file protocol. But this has to work on http(s) too. I'm testing on the file protocol but the solution will have to go online